# How to use WorldToScreenPoint function in a texture context?

Tags: rendering, coordinates, screen, rendertexture

I am rendering a scene into a RenderTexture and I have a set of 3D points. I want to convert these points from 3D to texture coordinate frame. It worked, when I rendered into screen and used `camera.WorldToScreen()` function. Now I have to render into texture. Is there any way to do the same as `WorldToScreen()` function does for the render/2D texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found that this function WorldToScreenPoint works good as well for RenderTexture. The question was asked because didn't found answer by googling and saw always the same problem while getting screenshots

Comment: If this is the way you solved the issue, you should come back and mark this answer as "accepted" so that the system and other users know that it is indeed a good solution.